# Is there any way to find distinct documents in mongo using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I actually want To display Full documents Without duplication

When I use distinct i can only display one particular field

How to display all fields without selecting that document which is repeated

Answer (score 0):

Each document in MongoDB contains an _id field which must be unique in the collection. Hence, it is not possible to have two identical documents in a collection. Ergo, iterating a collection with no conditions will return all unique documents (which are all documents in the collection).

Comment: can You Elaborate?